# Is possible to use EditorStyle on Unity in-game to do Horizontal Groups of Buttons?

Tags: c#, user-interface, unity-game-engine, unity-editor

I want to use EditorStyles on an in-game situation. I inspected EditorStyles class, and I realize that everything comes from:

```
        private GUIStyle GetStyle(string styleName)
        {
            GUIStyle s = GUI.skin.FindStyle(styleName) ?? EditorGUIUtility.GetBuiltinSkin(EditorSkin.Inspector).FindStyle(styleName);
            if (s == null)
            {
                Debug.LogError("Missing built-in guistyle " + styleName);
                s = GUISkin.error;
            }
            return s;
        }
```

Copied from: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/GUI/EditorStyles.cs#L425

The reference call is here: https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/GUI/EditorStyles.cs#L333

And this is what I use (on Editor): https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/master/Editor/Mono/GUI/EditorStyles.cs#L71

All this to do the following:

[image: ...]

I have to do the following:

```
 EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal ();
 if (GUILayout.Button ("Select", EditorStyles.miniButtonLeft)) {
 }
 if (GUILayout.Button ("Revert", EditorStyles.miniButton)) {
 }
 if (GUILayout.Button ("Apply", EditorStyles.miniButtonRight)) {
 }
 EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal ();
```

But, I want to know if there is any possible way to do this in-game. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot that there were a way of doing this.

With an Editor script, we will save on out disk Editor guiskins:

```
        bool saveAssets = false;
        foreach (var editorSkin in Enum.GetValues(typeof(EditorSkin)).Cast<EditorSkin>())
        {
            string file = Path.Combine("Assets", "StreamingAssets", $"{editorSkin.ToString()}.guiskin");

            if (!File.Exists(file))
            {
                AssetDatabase.CreateAsset(Instantiate(EditorGUIUtility.GetBuiltinSkin(editorSkin)), file);
                saveAssets = true;
            }
        }

        if (saveAssets)
            AssetDatabase.SaveAssets();
```

And then, we could just save then on Resources folder, and load it with `Resources.Load`:

[image: ...]

```
//
// Summary:
//     Enum that selects which skin to return from EditorGUIUtility.GetBuiltinSkin.
public enum GlobalSkin
{
    //
    // Summary:
    //     The skin used for game views.
    Game = 0,

    //
    // Summary:
    //     The skin used for inspectors.
    Inspector = 1,

    //
    // Summary:
    //     The skin used for Scene views.
    Scene = 2
}
```

And then, just create a method to return them:

```
    // Get one of the built-in GUI skins, which can be the game view, inspector or scene view skin as chosen by the parameter.
    public static GUISkin GetBuiltinSkin(GlobalSkin skin)
    {
        return Resources.Load<GUISkin>($"Skins/{skin.ToString()}");
    }
```

Everything else is done by using `GUISkin.FindStyle("whatever")`.

Answer (score 1):

Editor classes cannot be used in-game.

If you are developing a UI for in-game you should be using the [Unity UI system](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UISystem.html), the one with the `Canvas`, then something like the HorizontalLayoutGroup could sort things for you.

But if you intent in using the IMGUI, that is the legacy `OnGUI` way of doing user interface and I highly discourage you in doing so, you could use a [GUI Skin](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-GUISkin.html) with [GUILayout.BeginHorizontal](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GUILayout.BeginHorizontal.html).

Hope that I understood correctly and could be of some help.

Best regards.

Comment: Thanks anyway, but I remember how to do that.